# How to check is the form has not been "attacked"

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have to make some custom forms,
the thing is, I will need to use JavaScript to make them, here is a little image :

[image]

It's like a select, but in a carousel, so, I can know what items is selected, the thing is, I need to calculate a price over fields like that, and people can like, spoof the system, and just change the active element, make the element the cheapest with the element they really took, maybe the more expensive you see ?

But how can I ensure that the user didn't changed anything, I guess it will be an Ajax to ensure the information in the server, because they can't change anything on the server, but in the server how can I send the good data if the user spoofed it ? Maybe I could add on the HTML something like : data-server-element: 1, data-server-price = 50. But the data-server-price will only be here to calculate the price with Javascript and I would have an array in my server side which will tell me : data-server-element : 1 ====> 50. So if he change the data-server-price, he will pay the real price. But if he change the data-server-element he can do anything he want, I see how to resolve a problem, but that resolve add some more problems. I am certainly wrong in the process and in the logic, which is why I am calling on you to find out, because I cannot afford to let someone pay less than they should.

Thanks for your help.

(Maybe this question is already here on StackOverflow, but I didn't find out an answer that could help me, If so, I apologize, usually I do some research before I ask a question here)

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you've realized this! A lot of people don't, and we get horribly insecure webpages. In fact, you can take the idea even further - an evil hacker will probably not bother with your webpage and javascript at all. They will just make their own HTTP request from scratch with all the fields set to whatever they please.

There really is only one solution to this and you've also come up with it yourself - you need to validate and re-calculate everything on the server side. Just take the basic data (like which choices he selected) and go from there. You can even make your form in such a way that it doesn't bother sending the calculation results that were done client side. You can't rely on them anyway. They're only good for the convenience of the legitimate users.

Comment: Bit sexist! Not all hackers are male :) :)

Comment: Hello, "You can even make your form in such a way that it doesn't bother sending the calculation results" I don't want to do that. I would like to find a way to send one by one data, like a basic form would do. But I would like to don't have them false by something. And I don't see how I can send the choice of the user, the REAL choice I mean, not the false one

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Gah. In my defense, I was in a rush, and my native tongue doesn't have a gender-neutral "they", so we normally use "he" and it means either gender.

Comment: @ThéoBenoit - as Terry Carmen said - you cannot trust ANYTHING that comes from the browser. It can all be faked. So your server has to be ready for ANYTHING. If the data that arrives doesn't make sense, show an error. If it does make sense, verify all you can verify, then use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't trust anything that happens in the browser.

If you want a different price for different regions, calculate it on the server and send it back to the browser to show the user.

**However** do not use this price when the user submits the form. Recalculate the price on your server then use *that*.

There is no way to stop the user from changing anything or everything in the web page or the data that they send back to you. Never trust anything you get from the browser.